# Why is the Spark state growing slowly even in the absence of incoming data, resulting in OOM exceptions and executor termination?

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I am utilizing Spark's Arbitrary Stateful Processing API, specifically flatMapGroupsWithState, to manage the state. The timeout condition is defined such that if no data is received for a specific ID within one hour, the current state of the ID is retrieved and written to Delta Lake. However, we have observed that the Spark state is gradually increasing even when there is no incoming data, eventually leading to an Out-of-Memory (OOM) exception and termination of the executor

below is high level code

```
val statOut = inputStream.groupByKey(rawInputMessage => (rawInputMessage.Id))
      .flatMapGroupsWithState(
        outputMode = OutputMode.Append(),
        timeoutConf = GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout()
      )(updateState)
      

def updateState(id: String, inputMessage: Iterator[RawInputMessage], state: GroupState[DataState]): Iterator[OutputMessage] = {
    
    val outPutMsg = if (state.hasTimedOut) {
      val oldState = state.getOption
      generateOutputFromState(id,oldState)

    } else {
        val oldState = state.getOption
    processAndUpdateState(id, inputMessage, oldState)
   }
    
  state.setTimeoutDuration("1 hour")
  Iterator(outPutMsg)
}
```